# Angular style guide, where to put component services

Tags: angular

I have a **modal** component.
The style guide states that we should move complex logic into services for components: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#delegate-complex-component-logic-to-services

It also states that all singleton services should be put into a **core** feature.
So, where do I put my component service?

I want to share a function between my component and anything that is using it. So, if I create a modal.service.ts, should it go in the /shared/modal folder along with the modal.component.html/css/spec/ts ??

Comment: I would say keep the service with the component : when you will create another project and think "my modal service was nice to use, maybe I should take it in my new project", you will only have to copy/paste a single folder instead of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more of a question that involves personal opinions. Generally speaking, with the new provider configuration syntax `providedIn: 'root'` released with Angular 6, putting your services inside `CoreModule` is getting fewer benefits than it used to previously.

If your service is a companion with the component it provides, I would suggest you create an independent feature module for it. In your case, `DialogModule` would be the way to go. Putting it inside either CoreModule or SharedModule is also fine but the only way I would strongly against is to put your dialog service inside Core, and your dialog component inside Shared because it may cause you trouble for future maintainance and readibility.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, I was hoping there was a standard :( I too did not want to put it in core....